# Auth0 with Socket.IO forcing authentication

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, auth0, feathersjs

I need to protect services exported by Feathers database adapter, with token authentication. We did this for REST with:

```
var authenticate = jwt({
  secret: new Buffer(process.env.AUTH0_CLIENT_SECRET, 'base64'),
  audience: process.env.AUTH0_CLIENT_ID
});
```

To prevent un-authenticated clients from accessing REST services, we do:

```
app.use('/api', authenticate);
```

Access to websockets should be locked down, as well. I found some examples. The below should theoretically enable authentication for socket.io.

```
app.configure(feathers.socketio(function(io) {
  io.on('connection', socketioJwt.authorize({
    secret: new Buffer(process.env.AUTH0_CLIENT_SECRET, 'base64'),
    audience: process.env.AUTH0_CLIENT_ID,
    timeout: 5000 // 5 seconds to send the authentication message
  })).on('authenticated', function(socket) {
//    console.log('token: ' + socket.decoded_token.name);
    socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
    socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
      console.log(data);
    });
  });
}));
```

This is not happening, however. The client socket.io requests do not have the token, yet the server has no problem take care of them.

Where do I start looking?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to force authentication is to use [feathers-hooks](https://github.com/feathersjs/feathers-hooks). We also have a guide on how you can do [authentication](http://feathersjs.com/learn/authentication/) and [authorization](http://feathersjs.com/learn/authorization/).

Our docs are a little confusing at the moment so it's easy to miss, but we'll be fixing that soon!

Comment: Am I understanding you correctly that the recommended way is to utilize passport-auth0 etc? When you configured app to use feathers-passport after 'rest' and 'socketio' and hooks, are both 'rest' and socketio going to require authentication? Are those app.configure all that is necessary to create the proper "stack"?
I don't know whether your documentation is confusing. I have been doing Node.JS for two weeks. The abundance of packages is still overwhelming. 

I sort of figured out one way to forcing authentication of socket.io requests, but did not get my client and server to play nice, yet.

Answer (score 0):

I might have found the problem. When I use the below snippet [before io.on()] to lock socket.io down, it seems to work.

```
io.use(socketioJwt.authorize({
  secret: new Buffer(process.env.AUTH0_CLIENT_SECRET, 'base64'),
  audience: process.env.AUTH0_CLIENT_ID,
  handshake: true
}));
```

Now, I need to figure how to make the client and server play nicely.